# Maximum entropy distribution $> 0$ with vanishing probability at zero?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-entropy

I know that the maximum entropy distribution if $x > 0$ and the mean is known is the exponential distribution. However, a large percentage of the probability for this distribution is close to zero (relative to the mean).

What if I know that there is almost no probability of my distribution being close to zero (eg a lognormal distribution, a gamma  distribution with eg $k \gtrsim 2$, etc.)?

Is there a maximum entropy distribution $f(x)$ where:

- $x > 0$, and
- $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = 0$?

If there isn't a maximum entropy distribution of this type, is there some other reasonable way of choosing such a distribution?

Comment: Certainly there is.  For instance, require $f(x)=0$ for all $x\lt \theta,$ $\theta\gt 0.$  The maximum entropy distribution is an Exponential shifted by $\theta.$  If you merely stipulate the limiting value of $f$ is zero, then any sequence of solutions corresponding to a sequence of $\theta$ converging to $0$ ought to work, showing that the limiting requirement is ill-formed: there is a *supremum* but no *maximum.*  Topologically, you need to constrain your possible distributions to a closed subset of all distributions and this one is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

I very much doubt there exist a maximum entropy distribution under those constraints, usually for the maximization to work moment conditions is used. See for example [What is the maximum entropy distribution given the median (instead of the mean)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/361476/what-is-the-maximum-entropy-distribution-given-the-median-instead-of-the-mean/361796#361796)

Comment: Re "doubt:" see my comment to the question.

Comment: @whuber: Thanks, will extend the answer