# Maximum entropy distribution of a positive continuous variable with known mean and vanishing probability at 0

Tags: distributions, maximum-entropy

I am working on a problem where I know that the variable of concern $x$ is positive, and has no upper bound on its value and whose probability would vanish as we approach 0, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} p(x) = 0$ (I imagine a distribution that somewhat looks like a Gamma distribution perhaps, just the shape visually, not imposing any constraint mathematically).

From this question ([Maximum entropy distribution $> 0$ with vanishing probability at zero?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124611/maximum-entropy-distribution-0-with-vanishing-probability-at-zero)) I guess it would perhaps not be possible to find the solution with just these constraints.

To solve the problem, suppose I also add the constraint of a given fixed mean, $E(x) = m$.

The problem would then be to find the maximum entropy distribution subject to the constraints:

$$x>0$$

$$E(x) = m$$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} p(x) = 0$$

The solution would not be the exponential distribution because of the the additional constraint, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} p(x) = 0$. What would be the solution?

And if that is not possible, any suggestion for any not-very-restrictive constraints that can be added to ensure the existence of a solution?